# Is the normalization of an image in double a lossless operation?

Tags: image, image-processing

Lets say I have an image in double that goes from range 0.0 to 32.0.  If I normalize it to get the range 0.0 to 1.0, by dividing by the max value from the image, do I lose information? I don't know if it changes anything but I do this in c++.

For the format at first talk about jpeg, but then after if we talk about the signal itself, if I were to lets say apply a k-mean to that "array" of double, would it make a difference if it were normalized?

Comment: It depends on the image format.  Which are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaling a floating point number won't affect more than 1 least significant bit, which is nothing in the context of image processing.